# Dropdown submenu disappears in ie8 when page load

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer

Dropdown submenu disappears in ie8 but it works fine in ie9,chrome or firefox.I try it in different way, but its not work. [Here is the link](http://www.myeloma.org.uk/)

Answer (score 0):

your code is saying that `LI` is taking `height: 240` which you have given to the parent `LI`. Try rectifying that.

Comment: Yes, I got the problem. Themes default ie.css use display:block; I change it to display: inline; And it works for me. Thanks.